# JavaFx instance in FXML

Tags: java, javafx-2, fxml

I try fxml feature in javaFX

1. how to specify a title while creating TabedPane? the code below don't work

   ```
   <Accordion >
           <panes>
               <TitledPane>
                   <title>
                       <String fx:value="123"/>
                   </title>
                   <content>
                       <Text text="123"/>
                   </content>

               </TitledPane>
           </panes>
       </Accordion>
   ```

2 how to instantiate Duration for animation?

```
<Duration><Double fx:value="300"/></Duration>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

answer on 2
TitledPane extends Labeled therefore has property text

```
<TitledPane text="header">
            <content>
                <Text text="123"/>
            </content>

        </TitledPane>
```